# how to sent files using multer function inside a controller

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm following a MVC design. I need to upload a csv file to my local folder path and to upload it's filename to mysql database. with the code below i'm able to upload the file and the file gets saved in my folder. but the req.body is undefined when i do console.log(id).
api in controller

```
Documents: async (req, res) => {

  if (!req.body.pid) {
      console.log(req.body,"test")
  }

  try {
      let storage = multer.diskStorage({
          destination: function (req, file, cb) {
              let id = req.body.pid;
              console.log(id, "janko")
              let path = "./public/images/files/";
              // fs.createWriteStream(path, 'utf8');
              cb(null, path);
          },

          filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            var datetimestamp = Date.now();
            cb(
              null,
              file.fieldname +
                "-" +
                datetimestamp +
                "." +
                file.originalname.split(".")[file.originalname.split(".").length - 1]
            );
          },

          fileFilter: function(req, file, callback) {
            if (
              ["cs", "xlx"].indexOf(
                file.originalname.split(".")[file.originalname.split(".").length - 1]
              ) === -1
            ) {
              return callback(new Error("wrong extension type"));
            }
            callback(null, true);
          },
          
      })
      var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('csvFile');
      upload(req, res, function (err) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return res.end("Error uploading file.");
          } else {
              res.end("File has been uploaded");
          }
      });
      

  } catch (err) {
      
      console.log(err);
      
  }
}
```

route

```
router.post("/Documents", signupController.Documents);
```

I'm new to nodejs any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this was a simple mistake. I just had to send the file before the text key, ie i was sending the file first and the pid after. I don't know the clear  picture, but 100% working.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.